# Using php mail doesn't insert new lines

Tags: php, email, newline

In the following code the $message has new lines when displayed in html (wrapped in pre tags) but doesn't show them in the email (I sent it to my gmail):

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
include "../code/dbstuff.php";
$to = "me@mail.com";
$from = "";
function processMessage($arr) {
  global $from;
  $message = "Hello from me\n\n\n";
  foreach ($arr as $key => $val) {
    if (isset($_POST[$key])) {
      $message.=$val . ": " . $_POST[$key] . "\n\n";
    } else {
      $message.=$val . ": empty" . "\n\n";
    }
  }
  $message.= "Date: " . date('l F d, Y');
  from = $_POST['contact_email'];
  return $message;
}

$message = processMessage(array(
    "firstname" => "First Name",
    'lastname' => 'Last Name'
));
//save in db
$conn=new db();
$conn->insertMessage($from,$message);
mail( $to,$message,"From: $from" );
header( "Location: thankyou.php" );
```

Comment: For one thing, your `mail()` function lacks a `subject`, which may cause you problems.

Comment: That was actually it, the message is crammed into the subject. The problem the client reported was probably the entire message crammed into the subject.

Comment: So... problem solved?

Comment: @Fred-ii- yes, that must have been the problem. Thank you for the help. I;ll accept it as an answer if you would provide it as one. Otherwise I'll add it sometime later this week so this question won't go "unanswered"

Comment: You're very much welcome. Answer has been posted, cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The headers are lacking a **"subject"** parameter, and that will surely cause problems.

This:

```
mail( $to,$message,"From: $from" );
```

Should read as:

```
mail( $to,$message,$subject,"From: $from" );
```

while adding something to the affect of:

```
$subject =  "Incoming message";`
```

Answer (score 0):

In HTML mail, whitespace is ignored. Use `<br/>` instead.
If you want to use in your code `\n` you should use `content-type: text/plain`

Comment: Thank you for your reply but I'm not sending html messages. According to the documentation the mail is text by default: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php  I will try \r\n instead of \n although the original code used \n and the client started complaining after I changed some code. It could be they never tested the code I worked on and it was already not displaying new lines.